# EFInteractiveViews With Unit Of Work Raise An Exception Second Run

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a big MVC & EF6 project. I have decided to use EFInteractiveViews to Pre-Generated views. But it's raise "MappingViewCacheFactory is already set and cannot be modified." exception at second run.
How can i solve this problem?
Thanks

```
    private MyContext _context;

    public UnitOfWork()
    {
        _context = new MyContext();

        InteractiveViews
            .SetViewCacheFactory(_context,
                        new SqlServerViewCacheFactory(_context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString));

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the view cache factory before you use the context for the first time. I actually pointed this out in my [blog post](https://blog.3d-logic.com/2013/12/14/using-pre-generated-views-without-having-to-pre-generate-views-ef6/):

*Note that this code has to be executed before EF needs views (typically before you send the first query or the first call to the .SaveChanges() method) so make sure it is in the right place (for instance in a static constructor).*

Note that EF caches the model and the views in the AppDomain and therefore re-setting the view factory after views are generated wouldn't have any effect since EF will use the cached views for any context instance created in the current AppDomain. 
One idea to ensure that initialization happens once and only once and before the context is actually used is to use to it in a static ctor of your app. Another place to do to this would be to close to the entry point of your app but before you do any "real" operation on your context. I would recommend keeping the initialization separate from any regular context operations.

Comment: Please clarify for me a few aspects.
If I understand correctly ViewCacheFactory does the next steps at first query:

1) Register ViewCacheFactory instead of default view generation mechanism 
2) Pregenerate views and store them (to file or sql server table)

After this steps every subsequence queries use this "cache" to increase query execution performance

Comment: Q: 
1) If we unload out app domain and then start it again should we again to go through time consuming process of view generation or we can simply immediately read it from our "cache store"(database or file)
2) If we each time of "cold" execution recreate our cache then What is the difference with "Warm up" dbContext at app start? ( ie simply query to any entities on application start event or HttpApplication static constructor)
3) Perhaps there is factory to work with NOSQL (Redis)

Thx for help :)

Comment: EF needs views before sending a query/command to a db. If it cannot load them from anywhere it will generate them. They are stored in memory. It happens once per app domain. If you unload the app domain the process is repeated. With EFInteractiveViews however - if the views were saved - they will be loaded from file/db. For big databases loading views is faster then generating them. If the db is big the warm up query can delay your app (let's say it takes 1 min to gen views - your app will not be able to do anything related to db in this time so all requests will be blocked).

Comment: If the db is small-ish (my rule of thumb is less than 100 tables) I would not even bother with generating views. For bigger databases measure first to see if there is any benefit. I am saying this because after I released EFInteractiveViews view generation in EF was made much faster and view generation for the databases it took minutes before now it takes seconds.

Comment: So, for example if we will call EFInteractiveViews.SetViewCacheFactory (dbCtx, new FileViewCacheFactory (path)) method 
then we'll save "view cache" in specified file.
And then ( ever after appDomain rebuild/ restart) 
when we'll again call EFInteractiveViews.SetViewCacheFactory (dbCtx, new FileViewCacheFactory(path)).
"View cache" will be retrieved from this file (ie we won't generate it again)? Am i right?
Or maybe we need use another Method (for example EFInteractiveViews.GetViewCacheFactory( new FileViewCacheFactory)) to retrieve cache from file?

Thank you in advance

Comment: If you set it again after you unload the appdomain and you point to the same file as you originally did it will load the data from the file/db. If you haven't take a look at my post on this: https://blog.3d-logic.com/2013/12/14/using-pre-generated-views-without-having-to-pre-generate-views-ef6/. Hopefully it will answer your questions. Just in case the code is here: https://github.com/moozzyk/EFInteractiveViews